# Symfony and assetic cssrewrite filter using named assets

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I have a problem using assetic and the cssrewrite filter using named assets. I have defined a named asset in the assets.yml like this:

```
assetic:
  assets:
    mycssfiles:
      inputs:
        - 'bundles/mybundle/css/mystyles.css'
```

In my twig template I use this asset with the cssrewrite filter:

```
{% stylesheets '@mycssfiles' output='css/styles.css' filter="cssrewrite" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Using this config the result of the css has an incorrect url for the images included in the css file. But if I don't use the named asset it works correctly and the url for the images are rewrited correctly. This code works fine:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/mybundle/css/mystyles.css' output='css/styles.css' filter="cssrewrite" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Does the cssrewrite filter not work with named assets? I know that it doesn't work with the @AppBundle sintax but I don't know if it doesn't work with named assets or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: This is just a guess and I have no confirmation, but apparently the "@" syntax is what causes the issues with cssrewrite.

Comment: I know the cssrewrite doesn't work with the @AppBundle like [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#fixing-css-paths-with-the-cssrewrite-filter) explain, but don't say anything about named assets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I post my conf for fontawesome, i hope this is helpful :) :

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug: "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles :       [AppBundle]
    java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
    assets:
    font_awesome:
        inputs:
            - "bundles/app/bower_components/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
        filters:
            - cssrewrite
```

Twig part

```
    {% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
            '@font_awesome'
    %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. The problem was I was using adding a `combine=true` in the `{% stylesheets ...` code in the twig templates